Question about concrete mathematics double summation derivation

How did the author in the image convert the summation into a double summation? I can see how the double summation turns into the sum of squared integers but how would you go about converting the sum of square integers into the double summation?
I'm sorry if my question is in the wrong format or something. It's my first time asking on this site.

"i can see how the double summation turns into the sum of squared integers" ... That's how you know you can convert the sum of squares to a double sum. If A is the same as B then B is the same as A.

Here's clues for how to do the formatting: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Do you know how to compute the sum $1+ 2+ ... + n$?

$$k^2=k\cdot k = k \cdot \sum_{1\le j \le k} 1 = \sum_{1\le j \le k} k$$

Any thoughts on my answer, adeldude?

@GerryMyerson thanks, its very helpful, sorry for answering late i was busy these 2 days i couldn't even read the book

You write $k^2$ as $k\times k$, then you replace one of those two appearances of $k$ with $\sum_{1\le j\le k}1$.
